# Como limpar campos de formulario html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

variaveis javascript que referenciam cada campo do meu form

```
var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name^=check]:checked');
    var categoriaVeiculo = $("#codCategoriaVeiculo").val();
    var descricaoVeiculo = $("#descricaoVeiculo").val();
    var placaVeiculo = $("#placaVeiculo").val();
    var chassiVeiculo = $("#chassiVeiculo").val();
    var anoFabricacaoVeiculo = $("#anoFabricacaoVeiculo").val();
    var ativo = $("input:radio[name='ativo']");
    var value = ativo.filter(":checked").val();
    var codPessoa = $("#codigoPessoa").val();
```

Comment: Podes fazer `form.reset();` é isso que procuras? se não podes explicar a pergunta melhor?

Comment: A pergunta está longe de ser clara para que se possa responder à mesma de forma adequada.

Answer (score 7):

Podes usar assim penso que seja isso que pretende caso não seja diga

```
document.getElementById('campo').value=''; // Limpa o campo
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu código você disse que as variáveis se referem aos campos, mas na verdade eles se referem apenas aos valores, o mais correto seria usar algo como `var [SUA VARIAVEL] = $("[SEU SELETOR]");`, exemplo:

```
var checkbox = $('input:checkbox[name^=check]:checked');
var categoriaVeiculo = $("#codCategoriaVeiculo");
var descricaoVeiculo = $("#descricaoVeiculo");
var placaVeiculo = $("#placaVeiculo");
var chassiVeiculo = $("#chassiVeiculo");
var anoFabricacaoVeiculo = $("#anoFabricacaoVeiculo");
var ativo = $("input:radio[name='ativo']");
var value = ativo.filter(":checked");
var codPessoa = $("#codigoPessoa");
```

Para pegar o valor da variável `codPessoa`, chame assim:

```
console.log(codPessoa.val());
```

ou

```
alert(codPessoa.val());
```

Para limpar o campo você pode usar, algo como `.val("")`, exemplo:

```
codPessoa.val("");
```

Comment: Simples e direto, valeu.

Answer (score 1):

No Jquery não existe o método reset, mas você pode chamar o nativo do javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this)[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Teria necessidade utilizar Javascript se você precisasse resetar uma variável ou limpar um campo especifico, como proposto na [resposta do César Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52418/como-limpar-campos-de-formulario-html/#answer-52419). Se precisa limpar todos os campos, utilize um `input type='reset'`.

```css
input {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 250px
}

input[type='text'],
input[type='email'],
input[type='password']{
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

input[type='reset']{
  border: none;
  background: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 265px
}
```

```html
<form action='#'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Nome de usuário'/>
  <input type='email' placeholder='Email'/>
  <input type='password' placeholder='Senha'/>
  
  <input type='reset' value='Limpar todos os campos'/>
</form>
```

---

Deixe claro para o usuário que ao clicar naquele botão todos os campos serão resetados. Ou então, faça uma verificação antes de realizar a ação, como no exemplo a seguir:

```js
document.getElementById('confirm').onreset = function(){
  return confirm("Gostaria de resetar todos os campos?");  
};
```

```css
input[type='text']{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 200px
}

input[type='reset']{
  background: #9b59b6;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 18px
}
```

```html
<form id='confirm'>
  <input type='text'/>
  <input type='reset' value='Limpar'/>
</form>
```

---

<sub><sub>Em ambos os exemplos o CSS não tem relevância e foi usado somente para tornar a *view* mais 'apresentável'.</sub></sub>